# Tartiflette + FastApi auth

Tags: graphql, fastapi

I am building a tartiflette app with FastApi using tartiflette-asgi and I can't find a way of making regular FastApi authentication or dependency injection work.

The problem lies in how the tartiflette app is built and mounted. When doing

```
app = FastApi()

gql_app = TartifletteApp(..)
app.mount("/graphql", gql_app)
```

I have no way of specifying dependencies to execute my headers validation. I've tried using FastApi `include_router` but it simply doesn't work with TartifletteApp. I have also tried a small hack like

```
gql_app = TartifletteApp(..)

app.include_router(
    gql_app.router,
    prefix="/graphql",
    # dependencies=[Depends(get_current_user)],   # here I would add a token and get a user
)
```

I get the error

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 389, in run_asgi
     result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
     return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 181, in __call__
     await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)  # pragma: no cover
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 111, in __call__
     await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
     raise exc from None
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
     await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
     raise exc from None
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
     await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 566, in __call__
     await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 227, in handle
     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tartiflette_asgi/_endpoints.py", line 84, in dispatch
     graphiql = get_graphql_config(request).graphiql
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tartiflette_asgi/_middleware.py", line 18, in get_graphql_config
     config = conn["graphql"]
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/starlette/requests.py", line 68, in __getitem__
     return self.scope[key]
 KeyError: 'graphql'
```

I could implement the headers validation as a graphql middleware but I was hoping I could do it at theFastApi level so it applies to every endpoint.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a basic auth first, then add it to Dependencies instead of getting the current user this will add a Basic authentication to your endpoint

```
from fastapi.security import HTTPBasic, HTTPBasicCredentials

security = HTTPBasic()

app.include_router(
gql_app.router,
prefix="/graphql",
dependencies=[Depends(security)], 
)
```

Comment: problem is that approach doesn't work. I get some errors at the routing layer. I guess TartifletteApp is not meant to be used like that

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this without tartiflette-asgi. The solution is posted [here](https://github.com/tartiflette/tartiflette/issues/452#issuecomment-716553159)

It looks like:

```py
import os
import json
import typing

from starlette.background import BackgroundTasks
from starlette.datastructures import QueryParams
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.responses import HTMLResponse, JSONResponse, PlainTextResponse, Response

from tartiflette import Engine


class GraphQLApp:

    def __init__(self, app, modules, schema_path=None, error_coercer=None):
        self.engine = Engine(
            sdl=schema_path or os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "schema"),
            modules=modules,
            error_coercer=error_coercer,
        )

        app.on_event("startup")(self._cook)

    async def _cook(self):
        await self.engine.cook()

    def _build_context(self, **kwargs):
        return kwargs or {}  # add custom logic when needed here

    async def _get_response(self, request: Request, data: QueryParams, context: dict) -> Response:
        try:
            query = data["query"]
        except KeyError:
            return PlainTextResponse("No GraphQL query found in the request", 400)

        def _format_error(error: typing.Any) -> dict:
            import ast

            try:
                return ast.literal_eval(str(error))
            except ValueError:
                return {"message": "Internal Server Error"}

        background = BackgroundTasks()
        context = {"req": request, "background": background, **self._build_context(**context)}

        result: dict = await self.engine.execute(
            query,
            context=context,
            variables=data.get("variables"),
            operation_name=data.get("operationName"),
        )

        content = {"data": result["data"]}
        has_errors = "errors" in result
        if has_errors:
            content["errors"] = [_format_error(error) for error in result["errors"]]

        status = 400 if has_errors else 200
        return JSONResponse(content=content, status_code=status, background=background)

    async def process_request(self, request: Request, context: dict = None) -> Response:
        content_type = request.headers.get("Content-Type", "")
        if "application/json" in content_type:
            try:
                data = await request.json()
            except json.JSONDecodeError:
                return JSONResponse({"error": "Invalid JSON."}, 400)

        elif "application/graphql" in content_type:
            body = await request.body()
            data = {"query": body.decode()}

        elif "query" in request.query_params:
            data = request.query_params

        else:
            return PlainTextResponse("Unsupported Media Type", 415)

        return await self._get_response(request, data=data, context=context or {})
```

So I can just do

```py
app = FastApi()
gql_app = GraphQLApp(app)

@app.post("/graphql")
async def graphql_ninja(request: Request):
    return await gql_app.process_request(request)
```